# How to use .cshtml razor file as ui-grid celltemplate?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

In my ASP.net MVC web project, I am using ANgularJS ui-grid for better data display option.
In the other razo view pages I have used partial view load

`<partial name="TestPartialView" model="data.TestPartialData" />`
Now in the ui-grid, in a column I also want to use the partial view.

````
```$scope.columns = [
        {
            name: 'TestColumn',
            field: '..xxx',
            width: '30%',
            cellTemplate: 'Templates/TestPartialView.cshtml'
        },]  ```
````

But I really dont know how to do this. Also in my TestPartialView.cshtml, I need to inject a model class.
As a current alternative, I have defined the template again in the javascript file.But I want reuse the template.
Any idea?

Update:
[image]

So the above screenshot is my scenario. I will have a grid column statistics. And in the cell I will show bar chart based on some row specific model data.
Yes I have done this (as seen on the picture) with column definition.
Now the similar bar chart I have used a .cshtml file where a model class is passed and the view is loaded partially.
I want to reuse the partial view her in the grid also.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a Controller to return your target View. And then you call this endpoint to obtain the view as the response and add it into your cellTemplate.

```
$http.get("https://localhost:44391/Home/GetTemplateFromPartial")
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.columns = [
        {
            name: 'TestColumn',
            field: '..xxx',
            width: '30%',
            cellTemplate: $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data)
        }]; 

        console.log($scope.columns);
  });
```

The Controller will return IActionResult

```
public IActionResult GetTemplateFromPartial()
{
    LocalMallUser user = new LocalMallUser
        {
            id = 1,
            age = 18,
            user_name = "test_user"
        };
        return PartialView("_SayHello", user);
}
```

_SayHello.cshtml:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.LocalMallUser

<h1>@Model.user_name</h1>
<h2>@Model.age</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
- how can I pass the model "data.TestPartialData" , which I already mentioned in my question.
- As I want to use this in a grid view column, creating request for partial view would be the number of times of rows.

Comment: @rasoo I'm not sure if I misunderstood in some place, but I think it's ok to add model data into the controller(return view with the model). Could you pls point it out if I made a mistake?

Comment: I think you understood my problem already :) But for better understanding I have updated the main post with my real scenario.

Comment: Hmmm, I really have difficulty to understand what you updated in the question. What's your goal or where's the issue?